# using cut command in bash

Tags: bash, cut, wc

I want to get only the number of lines in a file:
so I do:

```
$wc -l countlines.py 
   9 countlines.py
```

I do not want the filename, so I tried

```
$wc -l countlines.py | cut -d ' ' -f1
```

but this just echo empty line.

I just want number `9` to be printed

Comment: @UliKöhler: I checked the link you posted as duplicate, which is `wc -l countlines.py | cut -f1 -d' '`, but it did not work.

Comment: Indeed the first answer doesnt solve your issue, but I believe a modified version of the second answer (which has the highest score) does. See my post below.

Comment: Note: The first answer at the other post seems to work any time the number of lines/words is > 999

Comment: @UliKöhler: Thanks for the suggestion. my file is small (only 12 lines). but it still not work. on the other hand, solutions posted here work. so I will go with this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use stdin and you won't have issue with `wc` printing filename

```
wc -l < countlines.py
```

Comment: I think that's a nice solution, but it will only work for a single file per `wc` call.

Comment: @UliKöhler - I totally agree with you but this is a direct answer to a question related to single file. It doesn't make sense to only retrieve the sizes of multiple files without knowing which size correspond to which file. If I run `wc -l * | awk '{print $1}'` who is to say which size corresponds to which file? And there will be one extra size output, the total size.

Comment: I agree. However one valid usecase I can think of (that was not asked for by the OP, but this question might be found by other users) is to list multiple files instead of `*`. Then you know the awk solution will print those lines in the same order as the input files. The total size is indeed a problem for multiple files.

Comment: This is not valid with BSD `wc` which also puts whitespace in front of the result if you pipe the contents into it.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `awk` to count lines. ([reference](http://www.unix.com/unix-dummies-questions-answers/140419-line-count-using-awk.html))

```
awk 'END { print NR }' countlines.py
```

- where **countlines.py** is the file you want to count

Answer (score 3):

If your file doesn't ends with a `\n` (new line) the `wc -l` gives a wrong result. Try it with the next simulated example:

```
echo "line1"    >  testfile #correct line with a \n at the end
echo -n "line2" >> testfile #added another line - but without the \n
```

the

```
$ wc -l < testfile
       1
```

returns **1**. (The `wc` counts the number of newlines (`\n`) in a file.)

Therefore, for counting lines (and not the `\n` characters) in a file, you should to use

```
grep -c '' testfile
```

e.g. find empty character in a file (this is true for every line) and count the occurences `-c`. For the above `testfile` it returns the correct **2**.

Additionally, if you want count the non-empty lines, you can do it with

```
grep -c '.' file
```

Don't trust `wc` :)

Ps: one of the strangest use of `wc` is

```
grep 'pattern' file | wc -l
```

instead of

```
grep -c 'pattern' file
```

Answer (score 2):

[cut](/questions/tagged/cut) is being confused by the leading whitespace.

I'd use [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) to print the `1`st field here:

```
% wc -l countlines.py | awk '{ print $1 }'
```

Answer (score 2):

Piping the file name into `wc` removes it from the output, then `tr`anslate away the whitespace:

```
wc -l <countlines.py |tr -d ' '
```

Comment: All the pipes are unnecessary. By counting from stdin like `wc -l < countlines.py` the utility will only print the number and nothing more. No spaces and no filenames and no need to `tr`.

Comment: This is implementation-dependent, Gnu `wc` does omit the spaces, BSD `wc` does not.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, wc won't print the file name if it is being piped input from stdin

```
$ cat countlines.py | wc -l
9
```

Comment: Unnecessary to use `cat` and `|` here. A simple `wc -l < countlines.py` will do. Though your answer is better than using `tr` or `awk` or `cut`.

Answer (score 2):

yet another way :

```
cnt=$(wc -l < countlines.py )
echo "total is $cnt "
```

Answer (score 1):

Use awk like this:

```
wc -l countlines.py | awk {'print $1'}
```